# Can not close android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I tried android MediaPlayer service to stream a music. everything is fine, the only problem is pressing back button when MediaPlayer is playing causes force close and get `at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)`
 below is my code to play and how I tried to stop and close media player, any idea?

playing:

```
private class Stream extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(url);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
            songProgressBar.setMax(100);
            updateProgressBar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(timeUpdate, 100);
    }
}
```

closing:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: U should not override the onDestroy method to stop the Media Player when onBackPressed() method called, its like a Service is forcely closed when playing, Try to stop the mediaplayer with mp.pause then mp.stop after then mp.release this is the normal process..

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    onDestroy();
}
```

with

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Try it...

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement onkeydown event maybe it helps :

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
        finish();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```